# modulus of radon nikodym derivative is radon nikodym derivative of the complex variation measure with respect to positive sigma finite measure?

Tags: measure-theory, complex-integration, radon-nikodym

I am stuck in the proof of Theorem 6.13 in rudin's real and complex analysis,First i quote the proof briefly "there is a function $h$, of absolute value 1, such that $d\lambda=h\ d|\lambda|$. And by hypothesis $d\lambda=g\ d\mu$. Hence,
$h\ d|\lambda|=g\ d\mu
$

This gives $d|\lambda|=\bar{h}g\ d\mu$ ,where lambda  is a complex  measure and  mu is a  positive sigma finite measure"

\I am stuck in the last line that how to show $d|\lambda|=\bar{h}g\ d\mu$ from $h\ d|\lambda|=g\ d\mu$.
any help will be appreciated.

according to the meaning of notation,$$d \lambda = h d |\lambda | \implies \lambda (E)= \int _E h d | \lambda |$$ for all $ E \in M$ and
$d\lambda = g dx \implies \lambda (E) = \int _E g dx$ for all $E \in M$.

Now
$\int E h d | \lambda | = \int _E gdx$ for all $ E \in M$,now
from  here how can I show $| \lambda | (E) = \int _E \overline h g dx $ for all $E\in M$?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $\bar{h}$ and note that $h\bar{h} = |h|^2 = 1$ by assumption.

---

More details in response to comment:

We are given that $h \, d|\lambda| = g\, d\mu$. The definition of this is
$$\int \chi_E h \, d|\lambda| = \int \chi_E g \, d\mu, \qquad \forall E \in M,$$
where $\chi_E$ is the indicator function for $E$.

If a function $r$ is measurable, then by approximating it with simple functions we also have
$$\int rh \, d|\lambda| = \int rg \, d\mu.$$

In particular if we let $r = \chi_E \bar{h}$ we obtain
$$\int \chi_E \bar{h} h \, d|\lambda| = \int \chi_E \bar{h} g \, d\mu.$$

The left-hand side is $|\lambda|(E)$ and the right-hand side is $\int_E \bar{h}g \, d\mu$. Since this holds for all $E \in M$, we have $d|\lambda| = \bar{h}g\, d\mu$.

Comment: this is not rigorous justification, because the notation meaning h d|lambda|=g du is basically integration over E h with respect to measure |lambda| =integration over E of g with respect to u.from this you have to conclude in the language of integration.because all this are radon nikodym derivative

Comment: see now my question this was not at all rigorous.

Comment: @VishnudasaSrinivasan updated my answer

Comment: now it is correct thanks.

Comment: @VishnudasaSrinivasan You may be interested in [this article about Tao on rigor](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/). I had hoped that my initial answer would give you the insight to fill in the rest, which essentially amount to writing down definitions.